# Websphere JYTHON Scripting - Get Active Spec ID

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

**Problem:**
Attempting to use the JYTHON command below and I cannot retrieve the id of my active specification defined at a node-server level in Websphere. I believe its a syntax issue but I'm not sure what.

**Code:**

```
AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/Server:myserver/J2CActivationSpec:myActiveSpecName/')
```

**Problem Notes:**

- I do not get a invalid object error so I believe I have the syntax right but it just cannot find the resource even though it exists.
- I am using the AdminConfig.getid() as a way to check if the resource already exists in order to do a modify or a create.
- If I use the following code: AdminConfig.getid('/J2CActivationSpec:myActiveSpecName/') it will find it but not if I use a more specific path listed above.

**Reference Material:**

[IBM Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html)

Comment: Did you check it is really bound in the server namespace?

Comment: Ya I created the active spec at the lowest level you can in the deployment manger, the node-server level. When I create the active spec, the scope I define is at "cells/mycell/nodes/mynode/servers/myserver" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containment paths are always a little tricky.  In my (limited) experience, even if you can trace the path by AdminConfig.parents, you may not always be able to use getid.

Are you restricted to using getid?  If not, here are some alternatives that will get you an ActivationSpec at the /Cell/Node/Server level:

### Querying using AdminConfig.list

This approach will list the Activation Specifications at the specified scope (in our case, the server), and grab the one that has it's name attribute equal to 'myActiveSpecName'.

```
server = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:mycell/Node:mynode/Server:myserver')
activationSpec = ''

for as in AdminConfig.list('J2CActivationSpec', server).splitlines():
    if AdminConfig.showAttribute(as, 'name') == 'myActiveSpecName'
        activationSpec = as
        print 'found it :)'
```

### Using Wildcards

This approah uses AdminConfig.list as well, but with a pattern to narrow down your list.  If you know your activation spec's configuration begins with myActiveSpecName, then you can do the following:

```
activationSpec = AdminConfig.list('J2CActivationSpec', 'myActiveSpecName*')
```

Comment: The listing does bring it back. Just yesterday I learned this little trick and I am going to give it try today when I have chance using the,AdminConfig.list('ThreadPool', 'WMQCommonServices(cells/mycell/nodes/servers/myserver*') gives back the threadpool id on my server. I am thinking this should work the same for the active spec since there would only be 1 at the node-server level.